# Facing a resource compilation exception in values file in android studio

Tags: android, xml, performance, kotlin, android-studio

```
Caused by: com.android.aaptcompiler.ResourceCompilationException: Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file C:\Users\devsi\AndroidStudioProjects\BasicBookApp\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml. Cause: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 47: com.example.basicbookapp-mergeDebugResources-34:/values/values.xml). Check logs for more details.
```

This is the error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:ns2="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <attr format="enum" name="animateCircleAngleTo">
        <enum name="bestChoice" value="0"/>
        <enum name="closest" value="1"/>
        <enum name="clockwise" value="2"/>
        <enum name="antiClockwise" value="3"/>
        <enum name="constraint" value="4"/>
    </attr>
    <attr format="reference" name="animateRelativeTo"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="appBarLayoutStyle"/>
    <attr format="enum" name="arcMode">
        <enum name="startVertical" value="0"/>
        <enum name="startHorizontal" value="1"/>
        <enum name="flip" value="2"/>
    </attr>
    <attr format="reference" name="badgeStyle"/>
    <attr format="boolean" name="barrierAllowsGoneWidgets"/>
    <attr format="enum" name="barrierDirection">
        <enum name="left" value="0"/>
        <enum name="right" value="1"/>
        <enum name="top" value="2"/>
        <enum name="bottom" value="3"/>
        <enum name="start" value="5"/>
        <enum name="end" value="6"/>
    </attr>
    <attr format="dimension" name="barrierMargin"/>
    <attr format="boolean" name="behavior_draggable"/>
    <attr format="dimension" name="borderRound"/>
    <attr format="float" name="borderRoundPercent"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="bottomAppBarStyle"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="bottomNavigationStyle"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="bottomSheetDialogTheme"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="bottomSheetDragHandleStyle"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="bottomSheetStyle"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="cardViewStyle"/>
    <attr format="boolean" name="chainUseRtl"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="checkedIcon"/>
    <attr format="color" name="checkedIconTint"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="chipGroupStyle"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="chipStandaloneStyle"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="chipStyle"/>
    <attr format="dimension" name="circleRadius"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="circularProgressIndicatorStyle"/>
    <attr format="string" name="circularflow_angles"/>
    <attr format="float" name="circularflow_defaultAngle"/>
    <attr format="dimension" name="circularflow_defaultRadius"/>
    <attr format="string" name="circularflow_radiusInDP"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="circularflow_viewCenter"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="clockIcon"/>
```

This is the mentioned file (the first 50 lines).

It is not compiling. I have no idea what do to.

It says there is illegal char at index 47 but the line of code looks fine. This is the file (from the path)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not in the file itself your xml is fine.

Problem is in your file path you have a colon `:` in your file path